# how to send a value to the server using ajax object after getting response send another value on a separate line using the same object

Tags: php, ajax

hi i'm new to ajax and javascript and i'm experiencing a a bit of a problem with
sending requests to the server.

Here's my code:

```
function process(){
 if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
   Selected_word = document.getSelection();
   xmlHttp.open("GET","/gwizz/scripts/definition.php?word="+Selected_word,true);
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
   xmlHttp.send(null);

 }else{
    setTimeout('process()',1000);
 }
}
```

i am using the function "process()" to send request to server when a double click lister is triggered on the document body. The response that i get from the server is an xml file and its content is displayed on a jquery pop-up modal as you can see in the "handleServerResponse()" function below.

My problem is that i want to send another request to the server after the pop-up modal is closed. I've tried doing this by using the open and send properties of my xmlHttp object and sending a request to a different php script right under the onClose() frunction of the pop-up modal. but its not sending those value to the php script.

How can i use this signle ajax object to send values to the server at diffrent stages of my code?. Any help will be appriciated. Thanks.

```
function handleServerResponse(){
  if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
     if(xmlHttp.status==200){   
        var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        var xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
        Definition = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
 $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({       
                onOpen:function(){
                        modal_open = time();                        
                           document.getElementById("element_to_pop_up").innerHTML = "<span style='font-weight: bold;font-size: 25pt'>"+ Selected_word;

                },
                onClose:function(){
                        modal_close = time();
                        document.getElementById("element_to_pop_up").innerHTML = "";
                        username = "beach";
                        xmlHttp.open("GET","/gwizz/scripts/logfile.php?word="+Selected_word + "&username=" + username + "&modal_close=" + modal_close + "&modal_open=" + modal_open,true);
                        xmlHttp.send(null);                 
                }               
        });
     }else{
        alert('Something went wrong with process!!!');  
    }
}
```

}